# Xpath for Find & Replace?

Tags: xml, xpath, replace

Fellow Forum Members,
I'm new to Xpath and have the following question. Let's say for example I have 300 separate XML files and I need to make a global text change that may impact only 40 of the XML files. Is it possible using Xpath to perform a find & replace operation among all 300 XML files? Let's say for example the words I need to globally change are these words, "LBRT Assembly" change to "LBRS assembly". Does Xpath offer the ability to perform such an operation?  I know Xpath is good at querying XML elements. However, can it also perform a find and replace operation? What is the best application available one can use that will assist one in coding complex Xpath query commands?   Any opinion will be greatly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever downvoted the question, I regard downvoting without saying why you did so as pretty antisocial.

Comment: Michael,  thanks for your post. It's very eye opening. It looks like I will be taking a long look at XSLT and XQuery since these two technologies seem to perform find & replace operations more effectively than Xpath.  You mentioned using a text editor such as NotePad++. I agree with you it's perhaps the easiest way to do it.  However, all of my  XML files are stored inside a Common Source Database (CSDB) linked to Oracle technology.  Therefore, I have no direct access to the XML files since all data ends up inside of an Oracle data base. Again, thanks for your post. It was very informative.

Comment: Michael, regarding the XSLT code you posted.  Is the correct tool to execute such code done by using a browser such as FireFox equipped with the FireBug extension?  In short, what I am effectively attempting to accomplish is to bypass the Oracle backdoor and rely on using a Xpath, XSLT, Xquery frontdoor solution to get full control of all my XML data. However, I would like to know what is the best XML tool one can use to execute Xpath, XSLT, XQuery code to a lot of XML files stored inside a CSDB? Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Matrix, you can bring a comment to Michael's attention by using @MichaelKay. As for this last question... you might consider posting it as a separate question, since it's quite different (progressed) from the original one.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm no familiar with CSDB so I can't help you with that aspect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XPath cannot modify an XML file. For that you need XSLT or XQuery.

If this really is a global change (that is, if you want to change this text regardless of the context where it appears) then I would be very inclined myself to do it using a text editor: that goes against the advice I invariably give which says when processing XML data you should use XML tools. But if finding the text to change does depend on the XML context, I would write a little XSLT 2.0 program to do it: it's probably about a dozen lines. The core would be:

(a) a standard identity template to copy elements unchanged

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(b) something to drive the processing:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="collection('my/dir/?select=*.xml')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

(e) a template to create a new output document for each input document

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document href="{replace(document-uri(.), '/dir/', '/outdir/')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

(d) a template to modify the text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'xxx', 'yyy')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Matrix: Another main piece would be the part that writes each input XML document to a corresponding output document; otherwise all the output would go into one long stream.

Comment: @LarsH, thanks, I have edited the answer as suggested

Comment: Is this identity template to copy elements unchanged missing a `|node()` at the end of the `match` attribute value?

Comment: No. We don't care what happens to comments and processing instructions, elements and text nodes and document nodes are taken care of by other template rules, and we don't apply templates to attributes or namespace nodes, so there's nothing else left for `match="node()"` to do.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.